# Dynamically change Form Action when form submitting

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
<form method='GET' name='search' action='index.php'> 
    <input type="hidden" name="searchType" value="all" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="first"/> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="second" checked/> 
</form>

<a href="javascript:document.search.submit()"></a>
```

From the form above, I want the URL data to be `index.php/searchType=all` when first checkbox is checked and URL data to be `index.php/` (to be empty) if second checkbox is checked. How am I going to do that? Is it possible to on or off the "hidden" parameter as the example above? I don't want it to be `index.php/searchType=` when second checkbox is checked but to remove the whole parameter name.

---

This is second question:

I want to inject some parameters in the Form Action, how could I do that? Is it looked something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:injectParameter();document.search.submit()"></a>
```

What am I supposed to write in the injectParameter() method?

Sorry about I am quite new in Javascript and web.

Comment: If you want a clickable JS trigger, using `<button>` or `<input type="button">` over `<a>` might be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, if you don't want the input fields to show up in the URL, you can remove them from the form before posting.

Untested:

```
var objForm = document.search;
if (objForm.vehicle.checked)
    {
    objForm.removeChild(objForm.searchType);
    objForm.submit();
    }
```

Is that your goal?

Also multiple fields with the same name doesn't work this way.

you'll maybe want to use radiobuttons like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="all" />
<input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="first"/> 
<input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="second" selected />
```

or create an array of fields like so:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='vehicle[]' value='first' />
<input type='checkbox' name='vehicle[]' value='second' checked />
```

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

An example `injectParameter` function would be:

```
function injectParameter() {
   document.search.action = "index.php?newParam1="+newValue+"&newParam2="+newValue2;
}
```

Comment: Just wonder, after injectParameter() we call submit() method, will this method overwrite the previous URL that we crafted? Because I have no idea how submit() method append the parameters into the Action URL.